# HCL Notes 11 - Javascript - context.text not working in firefox but works in IE

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, hcl-notes

The below code works in IE but not in other browsers.

```
var node = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
var eitems = node.getElementsByTagName("nib:ProcessRequestResponse");
txt = eitems.context.text;
txt2 = txt.replace("\n", "");
```

Gives error "eitems.context is undefined". I have also tried `eitems.context.textContent`, `eitems.context.innertext`, `eitems.context.innerHTML`. All gives same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `txt = node.textContent` to get the content of tag and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a HTMLCollection. Access the first element with

```
 var item = eitems.item(0);
```

or just

```
 var item = eitems[0];
```

Use `item` to get the content.

Comment: eitems.item(0) gives null and eitems[0] gives undefined. I need the complete content of the tag "nib:ProcessRequestResponse". eitems.length displays 0 in both IE and other browsers. But eitems.context.text gives the content of the tag in IE where as in other browsers it gives "undefined".

Comment: What returns getElementsByTagName()?

Comment: node.getElementsByTagName("nib:ProcessRequestResponse") returns [object HTMLCollection]

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(eitems)))`?